# More threads created than expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, zeromq

You could find the program [here](https://pastebin.com/H5fq732a)

I am building a program in message passing framework 0MQ. I try to implement what I posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096203/another-reliable-way-to-do-pull-push-sync-in-zeromq)

Program compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lzmq -lpthread`.

To run the program, pass one parameter as the thread number you would like to have. That parameter is then assigned to variable `worker_num`.

In main thread, I setup thread with:

```
  vector<thread> pool;
  for(int i = 0; i < worker_num; i++)
  {
    cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
    pool.push_back(thread(task1, (void *)&context, i));
  }
```

I would like to make sure all worker threads have successful connection to main thread before main thread distributes jobs to them.

```
  while(true)
  {
    if(sync_done)
    {
      cout << "sync done in main thread" << endl;
      break;
    }

    zmq::message_t sync_msg(4);
    memcpy((void *)sync_msg.data(), SYNC_MSG, SYNC_MSGLEN);
    for(int i = 0; i < worker_num; i++)
      distask_socket.send(sync_msg);

    for(int i = 0; i < worker_num; i++)
    {
      if(sync_done)
        break;
      if(i != 0)
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

      zmq::message_t res_msg;
      int ret = getres_socket.recv(&res_msg, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

      if(ret == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
        continue;

      int threadID = stoi(string((char *)res_msg.data()));
      sync_done = if_sync_done(threadID, sync_array, worker_num);
    }
  }
```

So what main thread does is: pushing #worker_num of `sync` msgs with its PUSH endpoint to worker threads each time and then reads confirmation msg from its PULL endpoint. If main thread retrieves #worker_num of confirmation msgs, then sync done. Format of the sync msg from worker is: the worker thread's ID in a string. So thread 0 would pass a `0` in string back to main thread.

But running the program I have:

```
$ ./test 1
main() : creating thread, 0
thread id:0
thread 0 receives: sync
thread 0 sends: 0
thread 0 sync done
main thread receives sync msg from thread 1 # you may get many copies of this msg
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Aborted
```

`main thread receives sync msg from thread 1` means thread are 2 threads created: thread 0 and thread 1. Any idea why? I did pass `1` as parameter. Noted that if you run the program yourself you may get other outputs.

### UPDATE:

Program updated: [here](https://pastebin.com/USDVwehY).

Finally I figured out what's wrong.

expected output, you see thread 0 pass a `0` to main thread to notify sync done:

```
$ ./test 1
input parameter is: 1
main() : creating thread, 0
thread 0 receives: sync
to_string 0
thread 0 sends: 0, with size: 1
thread 0 sync done
pass 0 to if_sync_done
main thread receives sync msg from thread 0
sync done in main thread
```

unexpected output, you see unprintable char is passed to **`stoi()`**:

```
$ ./test 1
input parameter is: 1
main() : creating thread, 0
thread 0 receives: sync
to_string 0
thread 0 sends: 0, with size: 1
thread 0 sync done
pass  to if_sync_done  # !!!!!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Aborted
```

So it seems that I use `message_t` incorrectly. So I need to ensure that before main thread passes the content to `stoi()`, the buffer still exists.

I will add an answer myself.

Comment: Off the top, `zmq::message_t sync_msg(4);` appears to create a message capable of holding 4 bytes worth of data, but `SYNC_MSGLEN == 5`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/  without including the terminating null character itself. `ZeroMQ strings are length-specified and are sent on the wire without a trailing null`

Comment: Right. But then, `task1` assumes the message is NUL-terminated when it does things like `if(strlen((char *)sync_msg.data()) == SYNC_MSGLEN) ...`. This is undefined behavior, unless ZeroMQ adds a terminating NUL itself (I'm not actually familiar with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zmq::message_t msg_back((void *)to_string(id).c_str(), to_string(id).size() + 1, NULL);
```

`zmq::message_t` constructor you use does **not** make a copy of the buffer, if [[1]](http://rtbkit.org/dox/0.9/zmq_8hpp_source.html#l00101) and [[2]](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-msg-init-data) are to be believed. Instead, it takes ownership of the buffer.

However, you are passing a buffer managed by a temporary; that buffer is destroyed as soon as the constructor returns. You have `msg_back` store a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use that pointer - e.g. trying to read the message on the receiving end - exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right. By adding `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));` before the end of worker thread the problem solved. Could you suggest a more reliable way to prevent the buffer from being destroyed before worker thread terminates?

Comment: Follow the rules of the toolkit your are using (which I'm not actually familiar with). Allocate memory in the way that toolkit expects, then pass it on to the message (which, presumably, would own it and eventually deallocate it). Or else, use the constructor that makes the message allocate memory, and copy your data into that memory (the way you send `"sync"`).