# sending serialized structure with Boost but getting input stream error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, zeromq

This is a followup question of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262775/more-threads-created-than-expected).

I am solving the first challenge from [2016 Marathon of Parallel Programming](http://lspd.mackenzie.br/marathon/current/index.html). This question is related to the first challenge: string parsing.

If you read the problem set of [here](http://lspd.mackenzie.br/marathon/current/problemset.pdf), obviously the 5th step is parallelizable, which is `[Try all derivations recursively.]` on page 3.

So I would like to parallelize the solution by implementing this below with ZeroMQ and Boost(to serialize the structure `res_package`, which contains jobs for worker thread and result to main thread):

[image]

The PUSH socket group in `main` is used to distribute tasks. The `PULL` socket group in `main` collects results from worker threads. Lastly the `PUB` socket group is for sending kill signal to workers.

There is a step to do sync between `main` and `worker`, otherwise the `PUSH` socket in `main` would send lots of jobs to the first connected worker. I quote from my post:

> So what main thread does is: pushing #worker_num of sync msgs with its PUSH endpoint to worker threads each time and then reads confirmation msg from its PULL endpoint. If main thread retrieves #worker_num of confirmation msgs, then sync done. Format of the sync msg from worker is: the worker thread's ID in a string. So thread 0 would pass a 0 in string back to main thread.

If main thread receives a meaningful result, which is an `Eval` with its second field as `true`(meaning the string is accepted by the grammar), main thread would publish kill signal. After all worker threads send back confirmation, which is the field `bool exit_confirmed` in `struct res_package`, main thread join worker thread and print final result.

The problem is, I got runtime error from Boost. I have no clue what happened:

```
# ./spec < ./spec.in
main() : creating thread, 0
thread 0 receives: sync
to_string 0
thread 0 sends: 0, with size: 1
thread 0 sync done
pass 0 to if_sync_done
main thread receives sync msg from thread 0
sync done in main thread
456Dynamic exception type: boost::archive::archive_exception
std::exception::what: input stream error
```

This exception is caused by line 912(from GDB backtrace). So what I guess is that the problem is about dangling pointer, or the received in line 909 in somehow truncated. But I don't know how to go further.

To build my project, there are some files you need: [spec.cc](https://pastebin.com/ebBgxFXU), [spec.hh](https://pastebin.com/KmRzQNJz), [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/SCgqT4GV)

The original project you could download from [here](http://lspd.mackenzie.br/marathon/current/string.zip). There are `spec.in` and `judge.in` for testing.

To install dependencies on Ubuntu, run:

```
apt-get install -y libzmqpp3 libzmqpp-dev libzmq5 libzmq5-dbg libboost-all-dev build-essential g++
```

One important data structure is:

```
struct res_package
{
  int i;
  Set <Stack> ls; // from worker thread to main thread
  Stack s; // from main thread to worker thread, job to process
  bool if_accepted;
  bool exit_confirmed;
  Eval res;
  bool set_nonempty;

// striped.....

  template <typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & i;
    ar & if_accepted;
    ar & exit_confirmed;
    ar & s;
    ar & ls;
    ar & res;
    ar & set_nonempty;
  }
}
```

Worker thread receives `Stack s` and see if the string could be accepted by the rule `s`. If so, it sets `if_accepted` to true, then sends back the `Eval res`. If no and there is multiple possible rules found, it sends back a set of all possible rules `ls`, and sets `bool set_nonempty` to true to indicate main to distribute those rules.

If you feel confused, pls post a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the serializing code in the post, but I found it in spec.cc:

```
{
    std::ostringstream obuffer;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oarchive(obuffer);

    tmp.exit_confirmed = true;
    oarchive & tmp;
    std::string req_str(obuffer.str());
    zmq::message_t res_msg(req_str.size());
    memcpy((void *)res_msg.data(), req_str.data(), req_str.size());
    sendres_socket.send(res_msg);
}
```

Here you send the stream before the archive is closed. Try explicitly closing it, or limiting the lifetime:

```
{
    std::ostringstream obuffer;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oarchive(obuffer);

        tmp.exit_confirmed = true;
        oarchive & tmp;
    }
    std::string req_str(obuffer.str());
    zmq::message_t res_msg(req_str.size());
    memcpy((void *)res_msg.data(), req_str.data(), req_str.size());
    sendres_socket.send(res_msg);
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example showing how to explicitly close archive? thx

Comment: hmm. So there isn't a function like `close()` to do archive.close() ? all right...